# XNA C# time to draw?

Tags: c#, xna, rendering, timing

As I understand it the Game Draw function occurs 60 times a second and update happens as many times as it can between those times. Is that true?

Whats the best way, in the Draw function, or a function called from that function, presuming that in my case Update is very fast, of asking if there is time there is remaining to draw. Alternatively, how does one find out if draw is taking more than 1/60th of a second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `Update()` and `Draw()` by default occur at most 60 times a second.

To modify `Update()` call speed, use

```
base.IsFixedTimeStep = true;
base.TargetElapsedTime = new TimeSpan((long)(TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond / 600f));
```

where 600 is the required tick number

> Alternatively, how does one find out if draw is taking more than 1/60th of a second.

You can use `GameTime.IsRunningSlowly`, which changes automatically if it's slow.

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime) {
    if (gameTime.IsRunningSlowly) {
      // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @alan isn't it rather normal for games to enable this things to be set in an option screen? Like antialiasing and resolution, and field of depth etc.? Then the draw method just draws what it should, and if the FPS suffer, the user can turn down the settings.

Comment: Actually I've seen modern indie games doing this on the fly instead. But that dosn't matter, in this case it's worked out on the go.